# Distribution of simulated chi square statistic vs theoretical

Tags: chi-squared-test, simulation, chi-squared-distribution

Imagine a 6-sided die. I roll it N times and calculate the Chi-Square statistic on the 6-entry table of frequencies of these rolls.

In my program, I calculate the chi-square statistic as follows:

$\sum_i (O_i-E_i)^2/E_i^2$

The distribution of this statistic is supposed to follow a Chi-Square distribution with DOF 5. The theoretical distribution of the above statistic, as far as I can tell from the literature on using Pearson's Chi-Square Test to test fit to a distribution, is not sensitive to the number of samples/rolls (number N).

However, in practice, it is sensitive to N.

Therefore, the Chi-Square Distribution cannot model this statistic for more than one particular value of N (but we do not specify N when we specify the distribution, only DOF which is related to the number of free variables specifying frequencies).

Yes, I do not know deeply the theoretical foundation of Chi-Square so I am looking for a way of understanding this seeming paradox.

---

I can put this question another way.

In [this](https://bitbucket.org/damienjadeduff/chisquaresimulation2018/raw/master/GenerateChiSquareDistributionFromDie2018.py) code, I have a simulation that I run M times (fixed high M e.g. 10,000). In each simulation I simulate rolling a fair die N times to get N samples and calculate the Chi-Square statistic. For each different choice of N I get a different histogram of the Chi Square statistic (similar shape, different scale). I also sample from the theoretical Chi-Square distribution with DOF 5 (M times) and get the same shape but different values. The 95th percentile of the samples from the theoretical distribution is around 11. From the empirical distributions, for N=200 it is around 1.5 and for N=5000 it is around 1.2 (this decreasing of the threshold would seem appropriate as I am increasing the number of samples from which my statistic is calculated, but certainly is not approaching the theoretical value). Obviously, if I were to use the theoretical distribution against an experiment with N=200 I would be overestimating the threshold that would be required to make a type-1 error 5% of the time when the die is fair (recalling the aim is to check fit to distribution - in this case a uniform). As far as I can tell, none of this converges to the theoretical distribution as either N or M increase.

---

Where is my fundamental mistake?

Thank you in advance for your feedback.

---

There was no fundamental mistake. Thanks to Glen_b's own simulation which gave theoretically appropriate results, I could see that there must have been a problem with the code, which there was. The primary problem was not the formula. Simply, the code was sampling from a 5 sided die where it should have been from a 6 sided die.

Comment: 1. The distribution of the chi-square statistic does depend on N. Have you seen the widely-used "rule of thumb" that the expected value in each cell should be greater than 5? (or any of a number of similar rules) ... Such rules exist because the chi-squared approximation for the distribution of the statistic is not very good when there are small expected values, but it's better as $N$ increases 2. However, if I follow what you're saying correctly you have some other issue that the one I am describing. 3. It's impossible to tell from the infor in the Q what it is you're doing wrong; ...

Comment: ... and your link doesn't work -- it wants me to log in. In any case, could you perhaps *explain* what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry about the link. Fixed that. From my experiments, as I increase N, the 95% threshold actually goes down (from 1.5 when N=200) but the theoretical threshold for 5 DOF is 11.1 (p=0.05).

Comment: But I take your point that the threshold calculated from the empirical distribution does seem to converge as N grows. Thank you.

Comment: In the die example, if I set N to 6, that is I calculate Chi-Square from 6 throws, then the 95th percentile is generally about 12 which is the closest I got to the theoretical threshold for p=0.05. Could it be that when using the Chi-Square distribution for Pearson's Chi-Square test, we assume the number of bins and the sum of the frequencies in the bins to be roughly equal? Because if I increase N, as I wrote, the real threshold gets too low to be comparable to the theoretical distribution.

Comment: Though I haven't read anything about that (though I haven't been able to delve into the theory of the chi-square distribution either).

Comment: I did a simulation myself. I don't get what you get. You did something wrong but your post needs to be self contained. i.e. you need to explain what your algorithm is actually doing.

Comment: Just looked at your code. I see an obvious error in your formula for the chi-square statistic. ... i.e. the first thing you should have checked. I am editing your question to explain what you're actually calculating

Comment: Thank you for editing my question to add the formula on the basis of my code, and thank you for pointing that out. I do appreciate your help. Unfortunately, that was only a change that I made to try and achieve convergence to the theoretical. Reverting my code to the non-squared denominator I get a growth in the 95th percentile of chi-square statistic, way beyond the theoretical (N=7 gives me 11, N=200 gives 51, N=5000 gives 1011).

Comment: I have reverted your question to relate to the error in your formula at the time you posted your question, which my answer discussed. Questions should not be moving targets where you get to keep revising it as issues are explained. Please don't invalidate an answer that points out a major error, and into which someone put effort because you then discover additional issues. This is not a forum for incrementally debugging your code. If you have a new *statistical* question, you should post a new question, but if it merely amounts to "where's the bug in my code" it is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula for the chi-squared statistic is wrong.

It should be $\sum_i (O_i-E_i)^2/E_i$.

When you see surprising or unexpected behavior, it's the obvious thing to check.

With a correct implementation of the statistic you should see a progression something like this:

[image: histograms of chi-squared statistic for the described experiment and the chi-squared density with five degrees of freedom]

Here we see histograms for your experiment compared to the $\chi^2_5$ density with N = 25, 50, 100, 200

As you see, things are much as one might expect -- the $\chi^2$ approximation is rough at N=25 ($E_i$ approximately 4 in each cell) and considerably better at $N=200$ (where $E_i$ is approximately 33 in each cell).

---

In case anyone feels the need to see it, here's my code (done in R) for N=200:

```
X2.200 = replicate(10000,
                chisq.test(table(factor(sample(6,200,replace=TRUE),levels=1:6)))$statistic
           )
```

This is not especially nicely organized, but okay for a quick simulation (I actually had this as a single line but it's a couple of characters too long for the window).

Comment: Thank you for editing my question to add the formula on the basis of my code, and thank you for pointing that out. I do appreciate your help. Unfortunately, that was only a change that I made to try and achieve convergence to the theoretical. Reverting my code to the non-squared denominator I get a growth in the 95th percentile of chi-square statistic, way beyond the theoretical (N=7 gives me 11, N=200 gives 51, N=5000 gives 1011).

Comment: So I'll update the formula in the question. Thank you for adding it.

Comment: If you change the formula in the question, it won't correspond to your code. You should fix your code instead and see if this fixes your problem

Comment: Thanks Glen. I changed the code before I changed the question. The link should reflect the fixed code.

Comment: The only change in the code was to the  was to the Chi-Square formula.

Comment: A major issue with the formula you had in the code at the time you asked is resolved by my answer. If you posted code you didn't wish to ask about, the consequences of you doing that shouldn't invalidate my answer -- just ask a new one -- but the new one needs to be about what you're trying to implement, not about your code ("Is this the formula I should use in my simulation?" is on topic, but "where did I make a mistake when I implemented an unstated algorithm in Python" is off topic)

Comment: Dear Glen_b -- so you are saying that it must be a problem with the code and that the results should not be sensitive to N as I am seeing. I appreciate the time you took to answer. I will simply go back to debugging. And thank you for adding the histograms now from your simulation. It is good to see that someone else is able to get the result I was expecting.

Comment: Yes there was a problem with the code but not the formula. Thank you.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ODOEnVSHr87JcIcHr6pBQMbucSSGdyEj/view

Comment: Your code is so concise! I should probably learn some R so I can understand it.

Comment: readability would be better if I broke it up, but yes, R is fairly concise and  simulation in particular can be concise: `sample` is generating the die rolls, `factor` is converting it to a categorical variable with 6 levels (because at small sample sizes it's possible to have the sample skip a category and we don't want that), `table` counts how many in each category that was set up by `factor`, `chisq.test` does a chisquare test (it figures out it's a goodness of fit test itself because it only has one categorical variable), and `$statistic` keeps only the test statistic from that test.